# What is the best way to save a large array in database?

Tags: sql-server, array

Currently, I'm working on a simple CBIR (Content-based Image Retrieval) and I have a question.

What is the best way to save a large array on the database? For example, I want to save the results of Canny or GLCM (Gray-level Co-Occurrence Matrix) which is very large.

Also, if someone knows about Image Retrieval techniques, Please tell me is it a good way to save all of the information which mentioned algorithms produced for comparison or not? If it's not, so what is a good way?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you just using the database for storage or do you need to do queries against the stored arrays in any way?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
No, I don't want to just save them, I want to do calculations on my data and retrieve them as arrays.

Comment: And I use the database to improve performance and speed instead of doing the calculations on my every picture in runtime.

Comment: What are you asking? I assumed you were asking about what data types / data structure to use but the answer you have received so far is about the process of transferring data.

Comment: Okay, I got it. I want to know how should I save those arrays in the database. For example, one way is converting them to strings and separate them with "\t" and finally saving them in just one field! or another way is making the fields responding to x, y and value of the array. I do want to know what is the best way to do it! What type of the fields should I use? How should I use? And how to do queries?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where the data is coming from:

- If you do not have a .NET application *and* you do have the data in a text file, then you can use the [BCP.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) utility.
- If you have a .NET application, then my preference would be to use a Table-Valued Parameter (TVP). I have an example of one (with .NET / C# and T-SQL code) in the following Stack Overflow answer:

  [How can I insert 10 million records in the shortest time possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770180/how-can-i-insert-10-million-records-in-the-shortest-time-possible/25773471#25773471)

Comment: @EdrisCG Yer welcome. Out of curiosity, what exactly do you consider to be a "large" array?

Comment: I like to discuss it. Actually, I should save about 4 vectors for 10,000 images in the database. The dimensions of 3 of those feature vectors are about 512*512 (Actual size of images). This is what that I consider as a large array.

Comment: @EdrisCG First, the structure of the data is usually best to represent as it really exists. But, that could depend on what the data is, which brings us to: Second, can you please update the Question with an example of one entry? It can be redacted such that you don't provide 10,000 items of the array, but instead the first 3 or so..I am unclear what exactly is meant by "512*512". Are those bytes or multi-byte elements of an array?

Comment: I know it's a little confusing and it is because of my English. Sorry. For example, I have 10,000 pictures with the resolution of 512*512. I have to feature extraction on these images and extract some vectors like Canny. These vectors represent in arrays. As I said the dimension of one of these vectors(arrays) is 512*512.
If you create them in c#, you should do this:
double[,] canny = new double[512,512];
For instance, 4 rows of one of my arrays is something like this:
0.5485369537, 0.00125733335
0.2558564485, 0.22455856982
0.3255666352, 0.22546927555
0.4225588745, 0.72394588997
...